# Can I patch a static method in python?

Tags: python

I've a class in python that contains a static method. I want to `mock.patch` it in order to see if it was called. When trying to do it I get an error:
`AttributeError: path.to.A does not have the attribute 'foo'`

My setup can be simplified to:

```
class A:
    @staticMethod
    def foo():
        bla bla
```

Now the test code that fails with error:

```
def test():
    with mock.patch.object("A", "foo") as mock_helper:
        mock_helper.return_value = ""
        A.some_other_static_function_that_could_call_foo()
        assert mock_helper.call_count == 1
```

Answer (score 19):

You can always use `patch` as a decorator, my preferred way of patching things:

```
from mock import patch

@patch('absolute.path.to.class.A.foo')
def test(mock_foo):
    mock_foo.return_value = ''
    # ... continue with test here
```

EDIT: Your error seems to hint that you have a problem elsewhere in your code. Possibly some signal or trigger that requires this method that is failing?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've tried your syntax and got the same error. Maybe I need to mock both parent class and the static function separately. I'll continue to investigate..

Comment: I also have the same problem. If you found a solution, please post it! ^_^

Comment: After trying lots of different approaches, I can confirm that this solution is not only the simplest one, but also that it works for static functions too.

Comment: It seams to be `from unittest.mock import patch` in Python 3

Answer (score 7):

I was getting that same error message when trying to patch a method using the `@patch` decorator.

Here is the full error I got.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/testing.py", line 136, in __call__ 
    result = self.orig_method(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/unittest/mock.py", line 1171, in patched     
    arg = patching.__enter__()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/unittest/mock.py", line 1243, in __enter__
    original, local = self.get_original()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/unittest/mock.py", line 1217, in get_original
    "%s does not have the attribute %r" % (target, name)
AttributeError: <module 'py-repo.models.Device' from
        '/usr/share/projects/py-repo/models/Device.py'> does not have the attribute 'get_device_from_db'
```

What I ended up doing to fix this was changing the patch decorator I used

from
`@patch('py-repo.models.Device.get_device_from_db')`

to `@patch.object(DeviceModel, 'get_device_from_db')`

I really wish I could explain further why that was the issue but I'm still pretty new to Python myself. The [patch documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock-examples.html#patch-decorators) was especially helpful in figuring out what was available to work with. Important: I should note that `get_device_from_db` uses the `@staticmethod` decorator which may be changing things. Hope it helps though.

Comment: That actualy worked for @staticmethod, thank you for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me:

```
@patch.object(RedisXComBackend, '_handle_conn')
def test_xcoms(self, mock_method: MagicMock):
    mock_method.return_value = fakeredis.FakeStrictRedis()
```

'_handle_conn' (static function) looks like this:

```
    @staticmethod
    def _handle_conn():
        redis_hook = RedisHook()
        conn: Redis = redis_hook.get_conn()
```